# Jquery plugins not working on ajaxed content

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins

I have some content that I am loading using jquery ajax. The content has jquery plugins attached (example a modal box).

My problem is that because the ajaxed content isn't part of the original dom it hasn't had the plugins applied to it.

How do I apply the plugins to ajaxed content??? Is there someway I can reinitialize i the plugins???

Comment: Question is to vague. Show sample of loaded content and detail which jQuery method you use to load the content. There are e.g. some calls which strip existing `script` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the plugin in the ajax success function like this:

```
$.ajax({
  //Stuff..
  success: function(data) {
    $(".selector", data).myPlugin();
  }
});
```

This calls the plugin on the matching selector only in the html that was returned, so it won't run on the rest of the page again.

Comment: Hell yeah I wish I knew how to do that before. Would have avoided alot of issues