# how to use jquery .delegate() with wrapped function on ajaxed content?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Suppose you have a page called /start.html, 
and in that page you have a wrapped function
that gets called when the body loads.

```
function eatApples() {  
 // some code  
}  
function eatOranges() {  
// some code  
}  
function eatFruit() {  
$(eatApples());
$(eatOranges()); 
}  
// call the eatFruit function on page load
$(eatFruit());
```

Now suppose you also have a page called /end.html, 
and this page contains ajaxed content. Furthermore, 
you want to call the eatFruit() on that ajaxed content.

Is this possible with jQuery's **delegate** or **live** functions? 
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you code should be

```
function eatApples() {  
 // some code  
}  
function eatOranges() {  
// some code  
}  
function eatFruit() {  
  eatApples();
  eatOranges(); 
}  
// call the eatFruit function on page load
$(eatFruit);
```

unless the `eatApples` and `eatOranges` return functions as a result.

Now if the `end.html` is being called with ajax, jquery allows for callback handlers to be executed when the ajax content is loaded.

The delegate and live function is use to control events that occur from user interaction.

If the new content meets the criteria specified when using the delegate or live methods then yes, it will work with the ajax loaded content.

For example, if you set a

```
$('.aclass').live('click',function(){
   alert('clicked');
});
```

then if the content loaded from ajax have an element with class `aclass` it will also fire the alert when clicked.

If you could provide more info you will get a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527489/jquery-plugins-not-working-on-ajaxed-content about attaching code to a callback handler, and maybe that's what I'll have to end up doing. But because I'm going to be using delegate for most of the other functions tied to ajaxed content, I was hoping it could be used for some type of 'load' event. Apparently not?

Comment: You could use the [ **Global** Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) for that.